# How to get year from POSIX date

Tags: linux, posix, locale

Mu current Locale is POSIX.

Output of command :

```
$ locale | grep LC_TIME 

LC_TIME=POSIX

$who -b

system boot  Jul 31 11:08
```

I just want to get system boot year.

is there any way to get.
Thanks

Comment: That is in no way related to C. Do not add tags at random!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`who -b | awk '{$1=""; $2=""; print $0}' | date -f -`

Or if you only want the year:

`who -b | awk '{$1=""; $2=""; print $0}' | date -f - +%Y`